# Can you ignore the first line of a sheet when doing a sort?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a fairly common problem that seems to be unsolved on stack-overflow ; when I sort a sheet, the first line (with the column titles) also gets sorted (in my case, sent to the end) and it's a little problematic.
Here's the code I use :

```
function SortByCriterias() {
  var spreadsheetID = 'drive_ID';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID).getActiveSheet();

  sheet.sort(10);
}
```

I looked for the sort() function specification, but didn't find any easy way to sort only a specific set of lines.
I noticed that I could sort() a specific range too, so I tried doing :

```
function SortByCriterias() {
  var spreadsheetID = 'drive_ID';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID).getActiveSheet();
  var rangeToSort = sheet.getDataRange()

  rangeToSort.sort({column: 10, ascending: true});
}
```

But the problem is the same since it appears getDataRange includes the first line.

I could probably use a hard solution by selecting manually everything except the first line, but I'm looking for a more abstract solution if it exists.

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The function `getDataRange()` returns a range starting from "A1" to the last Row that has content. So it's probably best to create your own Range, starting from "A2".

```
var spreadsheetID = 'drive_ID';
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID).getActiveSheet();
```

Assuming the columns are A to K, start from "A2" to skip the header, then use `sheet.getLastRow()` to get the index of the last Row that has content

```
var customDataRange = sheet.getRange(`A2:K${sheet.getLastRow()}`);
customDataRange.sort(10);
```

IF DON'T KNOW THE WHERE THE COLUMN ENDS, THEN USE THIS INSTEAD

```
var customDataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
customDataRange.sort(10);
```

In case you're confused, check the [App Script docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) for `getRange()`

```
getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
```

"

1. "row" here refers to the row your range should start from, "1" is header, "2" is next after header.
2. "column" here refers to the column your range should start from ie. "1"
3. "numRows" is obviously the number of Rows for your Range. You can get that using `sheet.getLastRow`.
4. "numColumns" refers to the number of columns to be included in your Range. You can get that using `sheet.getLastColumn`.

`THAT'S IT!!`

I didn't really take my time to crosscheck so there's a good chance I made a mistake somewhere, but Hopefully you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

The [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method can receive a function as a parameter, but I don't think you can specify what elements of the array should be sorted.

In your case, one option would be to use [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to extract the header (first line), sort the rest and then add the header back with [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

For example:

```
function sortExceptHeaderTest() {
  const dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  const data = dataRange.getValues();
  const header = data.shift();
  data.sort();
  data.unshift(header);
  dataRange.setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the range with `range.offset()` method.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows

Try to change one line in your second script:

```
var rangeToSort = sheet.getDataRange()
```

With this:

```
var rangeToSort = sheet.getDataRange().offset(1,0,sheet.getLastRow()-1)
```